# Audible app crashing on launch on Amazon Fire TV Stick 4K Max

Tags: crashes, amazon-fire-tv, audible

I've just bought an Amazon Fire TV Stick 4K Max (Fire TV Home Version 6341067.1) running Fire OS 7.2.5.5 (PS7255/2444) and no matter which Audible version I install, it crashes every time I open it. Here's the [Audible.log](https://drive.pauperis.com/s/ydz5zd4ri4N4i4E).

Of course, before uninstalling Audible, I'm deleting data and cache. Also, when I look for Audible in the Amazon Appstore, there's no result and it says by voice, "You're already an Audible member".

Is there a working version of Audible for Amazon Fire TV Stick 4K Max? Anyway, I just would like to be able to use Audible as I do with my phone.

Comment: You have problems executing an Amazon app on an Amazon device, have you contacted the Amazon support?

Comment: Not familiar with Fire OS, how did you install the app? If it's not shown on the App Store, then there's a possibility that it's not compatible with this device yet, and you have to wait for the developer to update it (as shown on [the Appstore entry](https://www.amazon.com/Audible-Inc-for-Fire-TV/dp/B01G4XZE3O), "*This release fixes bugs and **adds support for new Fire TV devices.***"). Also, I have checked the attached Audible.log, but not sure which is related to the crash since there were quite many errors. Could you rename the current log as a backup and start a new log?

Comment: Cross-posted from [XDA Forums](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/audible-app-crashing-on-launch.4377985/) (in case it's answered on there).

Comment: Yes, weird. Amazon app for a paid service failing to run on an amazon device, weird. BTW, I've just edited Audible.log link to point to a new Audible.log file which contains just one crash after clearing data, uninstalling and installing Audible 3.19.1 i found on Aptoide TV  cause i couldn't find the app on Amazon App Store. The device is used in Spain, don't know if there's any restriction about the app.